# ¿Cuando usar Helper y Service? Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

me surgio la siguiente duda, cuando usar un Helper y un Service? hice un curso en udemy donde el profesor creaba un service para poder manejar una cookie, creando la carpeta service en /App y creando el archivo php con su clase, algo asi:

```
class CartService
{
    protected $cookieName;
    protected $cookieExpiration;


    public function __construct(){
        $this->cookieName = config('cart.cookie.name');
        $this->cookieExpiration = config('cart.cookie.expiration');
    }

    public function getFromCookie(){
        $cartId = Cookie::get($this->cookieName);
        $cart = Cart::find($cartId);
        return $cart;
    }

    public function getFromCookieOrCreate(){
        $cart = $this->getFromCookie();
        return $cart ?? Cart::create();
    }

    public function makeCookie(Cart $cart){
        return Cookie::make($this->cookieName, $cart->id, $this->cookieExpiration);
    }


}
```

Despues de hacer el curso comence a hacer un proyecto propio, queria crear un service para formatear un numero como precio, pero comence a investigar y descubri tambien los Helper, en mi caso deberia hacer uso de Service o Helper?, cuando usar cada uno?. Gracias!

Comment: como dicen los nombres, son explicitos, helper es para ayudarte a hacer algo recurrente, como obtener el usuario logueado y un servicio es algo especifico no recurrente

Comment: @NicolasAldana entonces el servicio no se deberia de usar de forma recurrente? por ejemplo usarlo en diferentes controladores o views?

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia entre un Service y un Helper:

- Service:El service es mas para resolver problemas de un cliente, es para interaccion con el cliente. Estos sulen ser publicos con algun significado comercial.
- Helper: el helper es para resolver problemas internos de la aplicacion como un parse de fecha que reciben y sule ser privado

Entonces En tu caso con el formateo de un numero tal vez seria de ayuda el helper.

Comment: A qué te refieres con `resolver problemas de un cliente` y `Estos sulen ser publicos`? Públicos para quién?? Por favor proporciona un link al artículo o la bibliografía en la que has basado tu respuesta